# Use i18n tag for translating

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I have an issue with my new Vuejs project, I use vuei18n in the same way like an other project of my company, but in the new project the  tag doesn't work.
When I disable `silentTranslationWarn` in i18n/index.js I have this messages :

> [vue-i18n] Value of key 'pages' is not a string!
> [vue-i18n] Cannot translate the value of keypath 'pages'. Use the value of keypath as default

When I put my translations in i18n/fr.js like this, my translation works :

```
const messages = {
  pages: 'Pages',
};
```

But when I want to use  tag in the component, like in the old project I have the vue-i18n warns desribed before.
I have searched in the old project all occurencies of "i18n", "local", "messages" etc... but I have exactly the same occurency in the new project, in my package.json I have same version of vue-i18n

Did I missed something ?

Comment: do you correctly create the vue i18n instance? can you provide an example

Comment: how are you calling i18n? try using `$t('messages.pages')` in line or in your code with the `this`.

Answer (score 0):

@kalidou.diagne :

In my i18n/index.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

import en from './en';
import fr from './fr';

Vue.use(VueI18n);
const messages = { en, fr };

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: 'fr',
  silentTranslationWarn: true,
  messages,
});
```

In my main.js :

```
import i18n from './i18n';

...

const Mdm = Vue.component('app', App);

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Mdm({
  el: '#app',
  i18n,
  router,
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
});
```